# C++ Cout In a Variable

Tags: c++, http, request

I'm trying to build my first C++ application and I need a little help.

I have this line of code.
I want to use an COUT/CIN to set the variable and insert it there on [VARIABLE]

```
request+="GET /cast/api.php?num=1&msg=[VARIABLE]&src=Inquirer HTTP/1.1\r\n";
```

I have set the ff:

```
string msg;

cout << "Enter The Message: ";
cin >> msg;
```

I tried:

```
cout request+="GET /cast/api.php?num=1&msg=" << msg << "&src=Inquirer HTTP/1.1\r\n";
```

But that's really wrong. :)

Please advice. Thank you.

-- edit --

OMG what a stupid question i made. I forgot I can just use:

```
request+="GET /cast/api.php?num=1&msg=" + msg + "&src=Inquirer HTTP/1.1\r\n";
```

Sorry.

Comment: You can't use `cout` and `cin` to do all of that. You should take a step back and just explain the *goal* you want to achieve, without unnecessary limitations. If you want to replace the `[VARIABLE]` part of the string with a string read from `cin`, just say that. Don't say that it all has to be done with `cin` and `cout`

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
string variable;
std::cin >> variable;
request = request + "GET /cast/api.php?num=1&msg=<" + variable + ">&src=Inquirer HTTP/1.1\r\n";
std::cout << request;
```

As someone have already mentioned, are you sure you want to concatenate `request` wih the additional string, or do you mean to use `request = "GET ... "` for assignment only?

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
request += "GET /cast/api.php?num=1&msg=" + msg + "&src=Inquirer HTTP/1.1\r\n";
cout << request;
```

BTW: do you really want to += the GET?

Answer (score 1):

This may do the trick, voluntarily simplified and split in multiple steps.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  std::string var;
  std::cout << "Enter message :";
  std::cin >> var;

  std::string url = "GET /cast/api.php?num=1&msg=";
  url = url + var;
  url = url + "&src=Inquirer HTTP/1.1\r\n";

  std::cout << url << std::endl;
}
```

BTW, you might want to urlencode your variable if you use it in a HTTP query.